# How do I 'git diff' on a certain directory?

Tags: git

`git diff` actually runs a diff on all source code. How do I do this on a certain directory, so that I can view modifications on files underneath it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12123669/1815624 `git diff master..yourbranch path/to/folder`

Comment: @CrandellWS Ugh, I hate the duplicate system. That excellent link is to a very succinct answer for this question, but that question is marked a dupe. We either need some way to merge questions into one (better) or we need a "dupes now pointing to this question" section for questions like this one (worse). Though ime suggesting that on meta invites only .

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Provide a path (myfolder in this case) and just run:

```
git diff myfolder/
```

Comment: I'd like to use `git diff -- myfolder` to minimize ambiguity to git. The general notation for git diff (and many git commands) is `git diff [commit-ish] -- [path]` where commit-ish defaults to HEAD (where you are at now) and `[path]` defaults to the git root directory, but can be anything relative to your current directory. Without the `--`, git will guess what you mean, `[commit-ish]` or `[path]`. In some cases, this causes git to say the notation is 'ambiguous'. If I remember correctly.

Comment: This prints nothing when I try the method in the answer and the method in the comment.

Comment: @ray which means you have no differences between working tree and latest commit

Comment: For @ray and future individuals seeing this you can include the branches you are trying to diff between `git diff master..develop myfolder/` as @CrandellWS said in the comment on the original question. Git status will show you changes if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @ray make sure you are at the root directory. The path will be relative to your current directory.

Comment: What does it mean when `git status` shows changes, but `git diff` shows no difference? (Presumably the directory isn't tracked?)

Comment: @jvriesem `git diff` doesn’t show new (untracked) files.

Comment: what if the folder name with space?

Answer (score 86):

If you're comparing different branches, you need to use `--` to separate a Git revision from a filesystem path. For example, with two local branches, `master` and `bryan-working`:

```
git diff master -- AFolderOfCode/ bryan-working -- AFolderOfCode/
```

Or from a local branch to a remote:

```
git diff master -- AFolderOfCode/ origin/master -- AFolderOfCode/
```

Comment: Only one -- clause is needed after listing both branches, as in: git diff branch1 branch2 -- path/to/dir

Answer (score 34):

What I was looking for was this:

```sh
git diff <ref1>..<ref2> <dirname>
```

Answer (score 19):

Not only you can add a path, but you can add [`git diff --relative`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---relativeltpathgt) to get result relative to that folder.

```
git -C a/folder diff --relative
```

And with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the commands in the "`diff`" family learned to honor the "`diff.relative`" configuration variable.

See [commit c28ded8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c28ded83fc95be8157c851c8be179733a7d4b137) (22 May 2020) by [Laurent Arnoud (`spk`)](https://github.com/spk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e34df9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e34df9a6e591be60172e3308b429bd7d243dfce8), 02 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c28ded83fc95be8157c851c8be179733a7d4b137): add config option `relative`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Laurent Arnoud</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>
>
> The `diff.relative` boolean option set to `true` shows only changes in the current directory/value specified by the `path` argument of the `relative` option and shows pathnames relative to the aforementioned directory.
>
> Teach `--no-relative` to override earlier `--relative`
>
> Add for git-format-patch(1) options documentation `--relative` and `--no-relative`

The [documentation now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c28ded83fc95be8157c851c8be179733a7d4b137/Documentation/config/diff.txt#L108-L110):

> ### `diff.relative`:
>
> If set to '`true`', '`git diff`' does not show changes outside of the directory and show pathnames relative to the current directory.

---

Warning: Before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git diff --relative`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c8f491668e46d66290aec97caaf94fe2c1ecccbd/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L733)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---relativeltpathgt))</sup> segfaulted and/or produced incorrect result when there are unmerged paths.

See [commit 8174627](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8174627b3d32dc80cb477b3fa46971955f26c6b2) (22 Aug 2021) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c8f4916](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8f491668e46d66290aec97caaf94fe2c1ecccbd), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diff-lib`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8174627b3d32dc80cb477b3fa46971955f26c6b2): ignore paths that are outside $cwd if --relative asked
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Thomas De Zeeuw</sup>
> <sup>Tested-by: Carlo Arenas</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>

> For diff family commands, we can tell them to exclude changes outside of some directories if `--relative` is requested.
>
> In `diff_unmerge()`, `NULL` will be returned if the requested path is outside of the interesting directories, thus we'll run into `NULL` pointer dereference in `run_diff_files` when trying to dereference its return value.
>
> Checking for return value of `diff_unmerge` before dereferencing is not sufficient, though.
> Since, diff engine will try to work on such pathspec later.
>
> Let's not run diff on those unintesting entries, instead.
> As a side effect, by skipping like that, we can save some CPU cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Add [Beyond Compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Compare) as your difftool in Git and add an alias for diffdir as:

```
git config --global alias.diffdir = "difftool --dir-diff --tool=bc3 --no-prompt"
```

Get the gitdiff as:

```
git diffdir 4bc7ba80edf6  7f566710c7
```

Reference:
*[Compare entire directories w git difftool + Beyond Compare](https://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/compare-entire-directories-w-git-difftool-beyond-compare/)*

Comment: The equal sign seems to be wrong for git 2.17.1. Use `git config --global alias.diffdir = "difftool --dir-diff --tool=bc3 --no-prompt"` instead

Comment: Note that when using Beyond Compare for dir diff, you need to either configure it to follow symlinks (In a Folder Compare View -> Rules (referee icon) -> Handling -> follow symlinks) OR, add the `--no-symlinks` option so that the command reads `git difftool --dir-diff --no-symlinks`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant bit when you do `git help diff`:

```
   git diff [options] [--no-index] [--] <path> <path>
```

The two `<path>`s are what you need to change to the directories in question.

Comment: Well, maybe people (like me) are here because they tried reading the documentation but it didn't helped them. On my case changing those `<path>`s make things worse: without it at least it returns the diff of all files changed between commits but if I change those it returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the subdirectories, you can use

```
git diff <ref1>..<ref2> -- $(git diff <ref1>..<ref2> --name-only | grep -v /)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use [Beyond Compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Compare) as the difftool for directory diff, remember enable follow symbolic links like so:

In a *Folder Compare View* → *Rules* (Referee Icon):

[image]

And then, enable follow symbolic links and update session defaults:

[image]

---

OR,

set up the alias like so:

```
git config --global alias.diffdir "difftool --dir-diff --tool=bc3 --no-prompt --no-symlinks"
```

Note that in either case, any edits made to the side (left or right) that refers to the current working tree are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a diff tool installed and configured (ex: [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/))

```
git difftool -d  branch1 branch2 /path/to/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this if I compare two branches:

```
git diff HEAD branchX path/to/my/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is only one directory you are interested the easiest way is to navigate to that directory in your terminal and then type

e.g. to compare the current dir of the current branch with the same dir in **master** branch

*inside the directory you are interested to diff*

```
git diff master *
```

or if you are interested in the file names first

```
git diff master --name-only *
```

if it is a remote branch that you want to compare with, make sure you have fetched it first then use it the same e.g.

```
git fetch origin master
git diff origin/master --name-only *
```