# Differences for a certain folder between Git branches

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

How can I get a diff file for a certain folder between the *master* branch and a branch I have created?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

You can use

```
git diff master..yourbranch -- path/to/folder
```

Comment: Can I specify a certain committer and how to extract this diff to a txt file.

Comment: what do you mean by extracting a certain commiter? retrieve the last commit of this person?
To write this diff to a file you juste redirect the output like this ` git diff master..yourbranch path/to/file > filename

Comment: I mean to extract only commits added by a certain author in my branch.

Comment: but between which ones do you want to diff? the last one?

Comment: I need a diff for a certain author commits between master and mybranch

Comment: I get `fatal: bad revision 'master..develop_content'`

Comment: Make sure that you have the branches checked out locally if you get that error.

Comment: Alternatively, `git fetch` and `git diff master..origin/develop_content`

Comment: I tried this command but it is not showing all differences. Only new file is shown.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt `git diff` has a lot of options that you can learn via `git help diff`. In your case maybe you staged some of the difference and need to add `--staged` to the command in the answer to see them.

Comment: You now need to add two hyphens to separate the branches from the path:
`git diff master..yourbranch -- path/to/folder`

Comment: It seems I don't need the `..` between the branch names.

Answer (score 13):

`git diff` compares trees (as in hierarchies of source files at two different points in time), so it can't extract the changes done by a certain author. If you want to see what changes a user committed, then you need `git log`.

Does this solve your need?

```
git log --author=jdoe oldbranch..newbranch -p -- path/to/subdirectory > myChangesInSubdirectory.patch
```

This lists each commit done by *jdoe* between the two commits, printing them as a patch instead of the usual commit summary, limiting only to commits that have changes in the target subdirectory, and redirects the output to a file.