# Git | Export file names changed after committing into Git

Tags: git

```
$ git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
commit 2ca5c13aba662df60ace9945b5110b7589f0aad2 (HEAD -> devops, origin/devops)
Author: Sample Name <samplename@asdfgt88p12.asdfe.net>
Date:   Wed Feb 6 17:18:30 2019 +0000

    removing unnecessary lines

M       dev/Jenkinsfile1
M       dev/JenkinsfileFind
M       dev/JenkinsfileCICD-DEV
M       dev/JenkinsfileIaC
```

**git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD** command list files which are last committed. 
How can I export all these file names and path of the file names into a .csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the commands in "[How to list only the file names that changed between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552353/6309)"

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ > list.csv
```

Comment: @VonC- When I execute the same command in ec2 AWS server I get below error. Any suggestion. Same command gets executed without issues in my local terminal. Error:= `fatal: ambiguous argument '@~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @Kally That just means the Git version installed on EC2 AWS is an old one (older than 1.8.4): replace `@~` by `HEAD~`: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309

Comment: Thank you.. How can I also get diff for newly created files

Comment: @Kally use AM instead of M in your diff-filter: see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203

Comment: I am using command `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM @~ > list.csv`. But this command is only showing changes modified/created only to particular folder. Overall changes to repo is not showing up. How can git diff only to particular folder..?

Comment: @Kally "How can git diff only to particular folder..": https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382054/6309. "Overall changes to repo is not showing up." Use the magic pathspec `:/` (that I describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33449169/6309): `git diff ... :/`. In your case: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM @~ :/ > list.csv`

Comment: I want to check whether dags folder under my repo is modified/changed/added `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M :/dags @~ > list.csv'
Error:- 
`fatal: ambiguous argument ':/dags': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @Kally I uses :/ at the end of the command: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M  @~ :/dags > list.csv`

Comment: Still same error:( `fatal: ambiguous argument ':/dags': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @Kally And with `it diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ -- :/dags > list.csv`?

Comment: @Kally If not, try: `git -C /path/to/your/repo diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ -- dags > list.csv`

Comment: Still no luck. I tried both commands. It creates list.csv file but with no info on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188272/discussion-between-vonc-and-kally).

Comment: @VonC-- You were very helpful.. Really thank you much for your suggestions.